# PostgreSQL match multiple values between tables

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I have this query to insert data which is not present inside `mytab` from `temptab`

```
 INSERT INTO mytab SELECT * FROM temptab 
  WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT  * FROM mytab WHERE 
    (mytab .col1= temptab .col1 AND mytab .col2=temptab .col2))
```

I want to know if there is any other way of writing this query's condition part i.e. the last statement.
The above query works absolutely fine but becomes too lengthy when matching many more columns. So I was thinking if there is any kind of format some what like

```
 mytab.(col1,col2,...,coln)=temptab.(col1,col2,...,coln)
```

I need to match so many columns since combination of these works as primary key for my table.Similary there exist many more tables.

any views appreciated.

**P.S.** : don't hesitate to improve the query.

Comment: If you want that many key columns, implies IMHO that there is something wrong with your data model. A primary key consisting of two, maybe three fields is acceptable, more than three is very rare. BTW: Do the values in the keyfields occur only in certain combinations? (maybe show us some data?)

Comment: @wildplasser, ahhh having tables with max 4 cols combination as primary key. About data part there is no specific combination.

Comment: It is not a law, only a rule of thumb. Having a key consisting of more than ~ 3 fields in most cases indicates design problems. (it can occur when importing/transforming unnormalised data, but that's a different matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write it like this:

```
(mytab.col1, mytab.col2) = (temptab.col1, temptab.col2)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO
  mytab
SELECT
  *
FROM
  temptab 
WHERE
  (temptab) NOT IN (
    SELECT (mytab) FROM mytab
  );
```

Comment: @Kouber, nice work but i do not want to match individual rows between the tables but,only primary key values.